# How to create/move a file to the directory same as the program?

Tags: file, pascal, lazarus

I am using lazarus on macbook and trying to create a file that is in the same directory as the program is in.

I've tried

```
AssignFile(ReportData, GetCurrentDir + FILENAME);
```

but it returns permission denied, so I checked the path that it is currently in by doing

```
writeln( GetCurrentDir );
```

Turns out it uses my home folder instead of the program's directory. Is there a way to set the directory to the one the program is in? Because I will be moving the program to another computer and that the directory won't exist on the others.

Comment: A few problems here.  The directory where your program resides may well not have write access for the user that runs your program.  And there's no reason for the current directory to be the same as the directory where your executable file lives. Back to the drawing board I think.

Comment: In addition to what David said, if you saw a "permission denied" message and `GetCurrentDir` returns your home directory, then something else is wrong as well. I suspect `GetCurrentDir` may not apply a terminating '\' to directory name, so `GetCurrentDir + FILENAME` won't give you what you think it's giving you. It may be trying to write one directory above your home which you would not have permission to write. If you want the path to the program itself, you could try using `ParamStr(0)` and remove the executable name. But you may not have permission there either.

Comment: @lurker You're actually right! but now the ParamStr(0) includes the program as well ie. '/Users/username/Desktop/ProgramName', is there a way to exclude the program name?

Comment: https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/extractfiledir.html

Comment: Try to use/inspect `application.exename` (extractfiledir() of it).